# Why do previous sql statements get executed again?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm rather new to Spring, Hibernate, JPA and many other related facets of this part of the developing world. I'm hoping this is a dumb question with an easy answer, as I've lost some hours trying to debug my issue.

**In short, the issue is that Hibernate (JPA? Spring?) seems to want to execute sql statements it has already executed previously, despite my saveAndFlush-call. For inserts, this causes unique index / primary key violations.**

In a controller, I have this function, which needs to add or remove a relationship between a User and a ProcessDefinition:

```java
    @Autowired
    ProcessDefinitionRepository processDefinitionRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping({"/toggleFavorite"})
    @ResponseBody
    public int toggleFavorite(@RequestBody ObjectNode jsonData){
        // Get the data
        int processID = jsonData.findValue("processID").asInt();

        // Find the process definition
        ProcessDefinition toggledProcessDefinition = processDefinitionRepository
                .findById(processID)
                .get();

        // Get the current user
        User currentUser = CurrentUser.get();

        // Either remove or...
        int result;
        if(toggledProcessDefinition.isFavoriteOfCurrentUser()){
            currentUser.removeFavoriteProcessDefinition(toggledProcessDefinition);
            result= 0;
        }
        // ...add to favorites
        else{
            currentUser.addFavoriteProcessDefinition(toggledProcessDefinition);
            result= 1;
        }

        // Send to database
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(currentUser);

        return result;
    }
```

The User refers to the ProcessDefinition with:

```java
    @Id
    private String userId="";

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_process_definition",
            joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="process_definition_id")
    )
    Set<ProcessDefinition> favoriteProcessDefinitions = new HashSet<>();
    public void removeFavoriteProcessDefinition(ProcessDefinition processDefinition){
        favoriteProcessDefinitions.remove(processDefinition);
    }

    public void addFavoriteProcessDefinition(ProcessDefinition processDefinition){
        favoriteProcessDefinitions.add(processDefinition);
    }
```

And the ProcessDefinition refers to the User with:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "favoriteProcessDefinitions")
    private Set<User> favoritingUsers = new HashSet<>();
    public boolean isFavoriteOfCurrentUser(){
        return CurrentUser.get().getFavoriteProcessDefinitions().contains(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ProcessDefinition that = (ProcessDefinition) o;

        return id == that.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
```

Now, when I navigate to the relevant page and click the button to remove a favorite, the code is executed as expected (verified with debugger) and Hibernate launches a delete query:

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        user_process_definition 
    where
        user_id=? 
        and process_definition_id=?
```

A result is returned, the Ajax call is completed. I click another button to remove a different ProcessDefinition. Hibernate again does the above delete query. Then I click the button to add a favorite (yet another ProcessDefinition, its ID is 3) and I see that this happens:

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        user_process_definition 
    where
        user_id=? 
        and process_definition_id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        user_process_definition 
    where
        user_id=? 
        and process_definition_id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user_process_definition
        (user_id, process_definition_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

Why is it doing deletes again?

It seems as if something is holding on to the previous statements and executing them again. This is further supported by what happens when I try to add another favorite (ID=2). Because what happens now...

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        user_process_definition 
    where
        user_id=? 
        and process_definition_id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user_process_definition
        (user_id, process_definition_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
2019-08-21 16:29:08.254  WARN 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-08-21 16:29:08.254 ERROR 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_6 ON PUBLIC.USER_PROCESS_DEFINITION(USER_ID, PROCESS_DEFINITION_ID) VALUES 3"; SQL statement:
insert into user_process_definition (user_id, process_definition_id) values (?, ?) [23505-199]
2019-08-21 16:29:08.257  INFO 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2019-08-21 16:29:08.278 ERROR 8528 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_6 ON PUBLIC.USER_PROCESS_DEFINITION(USER_ID, PROCESS_DEFINITION_ID) VALUES 3"; SQL statement:
insert into user_process_definition (user_id, process_definition_id) values (?, ?) [23505-199]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_6 ON PUBLIC.USER_PROCESS_DEFINITION(USER_ID, PROCESS_DEFINITION_ID) VALUES 3"; SQL statement:
insert into user_process_definition (user_id, process_definition_id) values (?, ?) [23505-199]
```

Again with the delete, but worse, the previous insert (with ID=3) is executed again! Of course this runs into a unique index violation. But why is it trying to run the previous statement again?

Note that when I do a remove, followed (in a different Ajax call!) by a re-adding of the favorite, no insert is even sent to the database.

Note that when I do an add, followed (in a different Ajax call) by a different add, I always get a 'Unique index or primary key violation' with as value the ID of the first ProcessDefinition.

Should I be closing or committing something, is the saveAndFlush not sufficient? What is going on and how can I solve it?

Comment: How is your transaction handling?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have heard of these 'transactions' but haven't investigated. I'm not using any.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer If it's any help, I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, which apparently does some things for transactions.

Comment: You are using a Set, how are hashCode() and equals() defined for ProcessDefinition? Do they depends on mutable field you may update such as id?

Comment: @NoDataFound hashCode returns id, equals is also based on the id. Does this tell you something? I don't understand why you state that id would be updated - it is set when the ProcessDefinition is created and afterwards never changed. I'll add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: I'm telling that because if those method are badly designed, the set may contains twice the same value (because the hashCode() may have changed between two add/remove, this happens if the entry is added to the set before mutable fields are initialized). 
If the set contains invalid data, then Hibernate may also fail. 
You should try to print the result of remove/add method to see if your Process were really removed/added. 
You could also try to always returns 0 in hashCode(), that would be bad for the set performance but at least that tell you if my hypothesis is valid.

Comment: @NoDataFound I've verified with the debugger that the correct ProcessDefinitions are added/removed to the Set of the User object.

Comment: When I enabled trace logging, I noticed that Hibernate decided there wasn't anything to delete in the collection when saving the user, and then proceeded to try and insert everything. This reminded me of something I read - sometimes Hibernate tries to delete everything and then reinserts. This happens when you're using Lists. It seemed like this is what Hibernate was trying to do, but without the delete part. I switched from Set to List on both sides, and the issue has disappeared. Although this solves the issue, it's not an answer to why the above doesn't work, so I'll leave the question open

Answer (score 0):

add the following to the application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view = false
```

and use `save` instead of `saveAndFlush`

I'm not sure if it will instantly solve your problem, but I believe that you will definitely get closer to a solution.

another idea:

```
if(toggledProcessDefinition.getFavoriteProcessDefinitions().contains(currentUser){
    toggledProcessDefinition.getFavoriteProcessDefinitions().remove(currentUser);
    result= 0;
}

// ...add to favorites
else{
    toggledProcessDefinition.getFavoriteProcessDefinitions().add(currentUser);
    result= 1;
}
processDefinitionRepository.save(toggledProcessDefinition);
```

this way you don't load the references from both way.

You also need to add `@Transactional` to your controller method if you turn off open-in-view.

Comment: I've tried save before instead of saveAndFlush, that didn't work either. Open-in-view is enabled by default. I've also tried with it disabled, but that made no difference.

Comment: Thought maybe I should stress it a bit more that the function gets executed due to an Ajax call. There's no associated view.

Comment: sorry I meant spring.jpa.open-in-view = false. Otherwise you have a default transaction in each request.

Comment: I've tried making the change from the side of the ProcessDefinition and then saving that one, as you suggested. Now there's nothing being stored in the database (no inserts on adding a favorite, no delete on removing one). I've understood from somewhere this would be the expected behavior and one should always make relationship changes from the "master" side, which in this case is the User?
I've tried with both the @Transactional annotation and without - no difference.